# Comparing two lists of tuples and finding the frequency of the common elements

Tags: python, list, append, tuples

I have two lists of tuples:

```
myList1=[(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7),(8,9,10,11,12)]
myList2=[(1,2,7,6,2,1,3),(5,3,2,1,8,9,6),(11,12,1,2,5,6,6)]
```

I want to find the frequency of the elements in `myList2`, which are common to `myList1` and add them.

Something like this:

5

3

2

2

2

3

0

2

2

Explanation: 5 # In `myList2`, elements of `myList1` occurred 5 times. i.e
1 (2 times), 2 (2 times) and 3 (1 time) , hence 5. 
Same applies for other results. 
I tried looping over two lists and using `count`, but it didn't work.

Comment: is it an assignment? what solution did you try? :)

Comment: Pretty easy one, try and post if any problem faced. In SO, no one will just write code for you.

Comment: Ahsanul, I haven't asked for the whole code. I have mentioned that I have tried looping it over two lists and comparing every elements. As explained, I have used `count` but it didn't work and give 0s. And Python has many updated modules (which I might not be aware of), where such problems can be done as a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

myList1=[(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7),(8,9,10,11,12)]

myList2=[(1,2,7,6,2,1,3),(5,3,2,1,8,9,6),(11,12,1,2,5,6,6)]

```
count = 0

for el in zip(myList1,myList2):

    for t in el[1]:
        if t in el[0]:
            count += 1
    print(el)
    print(count)
    count = 0
```

**Output:**

((1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 7, 6, 2, 1, 3))

5

((5, 6, 7), (5, 3, 2, 1, 8, 9, 6))

2

((8, 9, 10, 11, 12), (11, 12, 1, 2, 5, 6, 6))

2